# Why I am unable to emit reducer function from an effect?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, rxjs6, ngrx-effects

```
  login$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(fromActions.loginStart),
      exhaustMap(action => {
        return this.authService
          .login({
            username: action.username,
            password: action.password,
          })
          .pipe(
            map(data => {
              const user = this.authService.handleLogin(data);
              return fromActions.loginSuccess({
                roles: user._roles,
                token: user._token,
                expiration: user._expiration.toString(),
              });
            }),
            catchError(error => {
              return of(fromActions.loginFailure({ error: error.message }));
            })
          );
      })
    );
  });
```

In the above code snippet the return to `loginSuccess` reducer works successfully, but same call to reducer `loginSuccess` doesn't works for below function:

```
  autoAuth$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(fromActions.autoAuthenticate),
      map(() => {
        const user = this.authService.getAuthDataFromLocalStorage();
        if (user && user._expiration && user._expiration > new Date()) {
          this.authService.onSuccessfulAuthentication(user._expiration);
          return fromActions.loginSuccess({
            roles: user._roles,
            token: user._token,
            expiration: user._expiration.toString(),
          });
        } else {
          return fromActions.loginFailure({ error: 'Login Failed' });
        }
      })
    );
  });
```

Function is being executed successfully, as there is one more effect which is successfully executed by both the snippets.

```
  loginRedirect$ = createEffect(
    () => {
      return this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(loginSuccess),
        map(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        })
      );
    },
    { dispatch: false }
  );
}
```

I am unable to figure out why the reducer is not being called in the second case as action is dispatched in both cases.

Have tried replacing `loginSuccess` with a different action which does not require any data to be passed , but still the code not able to go to `reducer`

Comment: What is the `user` object in each of the cases?

Comment: In both cases `user` is returned, only difference is in the second case, it can return `null` also, but to check for that `if` the condition is there

Comment: I mean, could you show us exacly how `user` object looks like? NgRx may not call the reducer if you are passing something not serializable e.g. `Date` object, and it seems that `user._expiration` is a `Date`.

Comment: Correct it is a `Date`, but it is `Date` in the first case also and I tried to stringify it also, but in first case in-store it is stored as a string.

Comment: @Shlang as per your suggestion explicitly setting it to string , updated the code in question also still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You should use `switchMap` instead of `map` to preserve the Observable result:

```
 autoAuth$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(fromActions.autoAuthenticate),
      switchMap(() => { // switchMap here
        const user = this.authService.getAuthDataFromLocalStorage();
        if (user && user._expiration && user._expiration > new Date()) {
          this.authService.onSuccessfulAuthentication(user._expiration);
          return of(fromActions.loginSuccess({
            roles: user._roles,
            token: user._token,
            expiration: user._expiration.toString(),
          }));
        } else {
          return of(fromActions.loginFailure({ error: 'Login Failed' }));
        }
      })
    );
  });
```

Comment: I was also thinking the issue is in map, but I am new to `rxjs`, after changing it to `switchMap` getting the error `Type '{ roles: string[]; token: string; expiration: string; } & TypedAction<"[Auth] Login Success">' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.`

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer as well: You are supposed to return an observable from `switchMap`, so what you need to do is wrap your returned action with an `of` to turn it into an Observable

Comment: Thanks, @Razvan for the help, but it worked with `map` also, my bad was calling the `action` from a different module where the reducer was not registered.